# nGrams in apache mahout

Tags: mahout, bayesian, n-gram

I am running the naive bayes classifier algorithm through apache mahout. We have the option to set up the gram size while training and running the algorithm's instance.

Changing my n-Gram size from 1 to 2, changes the resulting classification drastically. Why does this happen? How does n-Grams size make a drastic change in the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1-grams are words. 2-grams (or bigrams) are pairs of words. It's like classifying documents based on the existence of "United" and "States", or "United States". Using bigrams can have some space and performance implications, but probably will give better results than 1-grams.

Comment: Does that mean ngrams are directly proportional to accuracy and inversely proportional to scalability?

Comment: No, it's nothing like that simple. Accuracy would depend on your corpus. For example, I imagine bigrams are more helpful for classification on documents with many significant phrases or proper nouns, like legal documents. Scalability is a separate question as you can decide how many n-grams to care about separately.